# Privatemsg through a Multi Site configuration?

Tags: 7, multi-sites, privatemsg

Is it possible to do such a thing for users in site 1 to message users in site 2 and visa versa? Using the Privatemsg module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-site is just a way to share code. Different sites are completely separated and know nothing of each other*.

There might be ways to theoretically do this using special recipient types, it would have to use services (or raw SQL queries) to another drupal installation, multi-site or not. And it wouldn't be easy to implement and likely also be very slow.

*With the exception of shared tables, but if you'd share your users, you wouldn't have different users in the first place.

Comment: So in theory if the user tables were shared then it could work?

Comment: If you would share the user table, all tables needed by that (like users_roles), and all privatemsg tables, then yes, it might. However, then all you have is a shared user base, there are no user 1 from site A and user 2 from site B, because all users exist on all sites.